# Always have HDR ON in Windows 11 with OLED display?

Tags: windows-11, hdr

My question is mainly about using OLED DisplayHDR True Black TVs/displays with Windows 11.

I'm wondering if always having HDR ON is a bad idea, say, if the colors of SDR content will become inaccurate? How does Windows 11 display SDR content in HDR mode--is the "conversion" lossy? If lossy, why isn't lossless "mapping" possible because I thought HDR covers more color space than SDR?

Comment: It looks really bad. It stretches the limited gamut of SDR to try fill the space of HDR - result… over-bright, over-punched images. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451578/macbook-pro-14-2021-overexposing-when-brightness-is-low/451580#451580 The images in the answer are what it should look like vs what it does look like in HDR [this is even before this particular user tried to enable Apple's XDR 'even brighter than bright' option, which is what their question was actually about.]

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin Can you help me understand what's the reason behind "stretches the limited gamut of SDR to try fill the space of HDR"? If HDR covers more color space than SDR, a lossless mapping should be possible and sounds a better approach?

Comment: Theoretically, someone could design a 3D LUT to map one to the other - but there's no point. Why convert something to a format it won't look any different in, when you can just disable HDR for non-HDR images. It's hard enough mapping a computer image to a TV anyway - they are designed for totally different things. I've just spent 3 days setting up my new AVR to my existing TV, cable box & HTPC, trying to get the colour back to how it should be. I have a hardware colorimeter to help & it still took me about 8 calibrations at various parameters until I was happy.

Comment: The computer's desktop looks absolutely abysmal now, because I'm aiming for Rec709, on a screen that can do BT2020… but the computer's GPU can't… fun, fun, fun. Movies look OK, though, which is the whole idea.